# My numpy is latest but TensorBoard says it's old one

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorboard

```
$pip list

numpy(1.11.1)
```

My numpy is latest and I am sure it could be used in python environment.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.11.1
```

however I use TensorBoard

```
$ tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/basic_rnn/logdir
```

it shows this error

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
```

What causes this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `tensorboard` command is linked against the wrong Python environment. Make sure that `tensorflow` uses the same Python interpreter/virtual environment as you checked your numpy installation with. Also check your `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` and take a look at `sys.path` and `sys.prefix` to see if there are some paths mixed up.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head!. Thank you very much. I found out that the tensorflow environment links the other python environment.